# How to switch an IP from an instance to another with gcloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ip, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Is there a way to "detach" a reserved internal or external IP address from a VM to assign it to another instance with the **gcloud** command?

I want to do this as I'm scripting with Python and want to automate this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following commands might help you -

[1]. To reserve external ip addresses.

```
gcloud compute addresses create mysecond  \
    --region=us-central1
```

[2]. To unset the external ip address.

```
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config instance-1 \
 --access-config-name="External NAT"
```

[3]. To assign a new external ip address to a resource.

```
gcloud compute instances add-access-config instance-1 \
--access-config-name="External NAT" --address=0.0.0.0(Your external ip address)
```

[4]. To list available external ip addresses in project

```
gcloud compute addresses list
```

gcp public documentation link -

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address